# Vocabulary option with bigrams for sklearn CountVectorizor returns array of zeros

Tags: python, scikit-learn, n-gram

I want to extract bi-grams from one array, take all of the bigrams with frequency greater than 100, and then score a second array using the reduced vocabulary.

It seems like the vocabulary option should give me what I need but it doesn't seem to be working.  Even feeding the output of one directly to the other just results in a (correctly shaped) array of zeros.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

docs = ['run fast into a bush','run fast into a tree','run slow','run fast']

# Collect bigrams
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (2,2))
vectorizer.fit(docs)
vocab = vectorizer.vocabulary_

# Score the exact same data
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
output = vectorizer.transform(docs)

# Demonstrate that the array is all zeros
print "Length of vocab", len(vocab)
print output.A



Length of vocab 5
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just caught it.  You need to specify the ngram_range in the second instance (it does not automatically interpret unigrams vs bigrams.)

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab ,ngram_range = (2,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

create a corpus of tokenized words.  set the ngram to 3 there are a odd number of words, otherwise set to 2 for even.   Create a bag of words matrix.   Create a dataframe with the bag of word matrix and get the vectorizer word as features.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk

docs = ['run fast into a bush','run fast into a tree','run slow','run fast']
str_buffer=" ".join(docs)
#print(str_buffer)
corpus=nltk.word_tokenize(str_buffer)

vectorizer_ng2=CountVectorizer(ngram_range=range(1,3),stop_words='english')
bow_matrix=vectorizer_ng2.fit_transform(corpus)

print(bow_matrix.toarray())
bow_df = pd.DataFrame(bow_matrix.toarray())
bow_df.columns = vectorizer_ng2.get_feature_names()
print(bow_df)
```

output:

```
bush  fast  run  slow  tree
0      0     0    1     0     0
1      0     1    0     0     0
2      0     0    0     0     0
3      0     0    0     0     0
4      1     0    0     0     0
5      0     0    1     0     0
6      0     1    0     0     0
7      0     0    0     0     0
8      0     0    0     0     0
9      0     0    0     0     1
10     0     0    1     0     0
11     0     0    0     1     0
12     0     0    1     0     0
13     0     1    0     0     0
```